# Asyncio and multiprocessing.Process- how to pass a coroutine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I've got a coroutine which is scraping some data. I'm trying to add multiprocessing to speed it up. I've come up with using multiprocesesing.Process. My coroutine is called *fetch_students_pages*

What I'm trying to do is to pass this coroutine as target to Process class:

```
    def fetch_students_concurrently(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            Process(target=self.fetch_students_pages).start()
```

but if fails with:

> /usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py:99: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'StudentPageParser.fetch_students_pages' was never awaited
>     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>   RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Is there a way to await it or use another solution instead?

Comment: you should not mix Process and coroutine in such a way - coroutines are managed by event loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `map()` instead:

```
cores = 8

with Pool(cores) as p:
    p.map(self.fetch_students_pages, range(cores))
```

Comment: this returns - AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove' . Actually this error appeared multiple times every time I tried using Pool/ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: Yeah, I'll grant you that _is_ a drawback of using `multiprocessing`. You have a "hard to serialize" object defined at the time you call `map()`. Your application is large and complex. Start a new app that is very very simple, just `sleep()` / `print()` in the helper and in the parent, to verify you have several simultaneous workers. Then build it up, adding more things from your original app until it breaks. Consider creating objects in the helper rather than in the parent. Consider deferring complex `import` statements until the helper has started running.